# Binary Reader problems

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, binaryreader

When I run my program the code below comes up with an error:

```
///////////////////////////// Read in the selected //////////////
BinaryReader br2 = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(directoryToSearch2),
                                    System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);

var Hexbytes = new List<string>();

///////////////////////////// Read in offset ////////////////
for (int a = 0x12 ; a <= 0x26; a++)
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = a;
    Hexbytes.Add(br.ReadByte().ToString("X2"));
}
```

The main line the debugger doesn't like is this `br.BaseStream.Position = a;`.

It states that "*NullReferenceException was unhandled*" and "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*"

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: where is br defined in your code section

Comment: Can we see the definition for br?  Or did you mean br2?

Comment: I meant br2 ... I never realised until you pointed out that it is meant to be br2 ... I feel so stupid, specially I have sat here for over an hour :( ... I suppose that is what you get for badly naming variables .... Thank you so much dude

Comment: Doesn't `br.ReadByte()` increment  the position by one byte anyways? You shouldn't have to change the position each time.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you posted, we can't tell what `br` is. A `NullReferenceException` is cased when one of the objects used is null. In the case of your exception, the underlying `BaseStream` could be null or `br` itself is null.

When the debugger breaks, hover over `br` and see what it shows you, if it isn't null, scroll through the properties to find `BaseStream` and see if that is null.

My guess? You create a new BinaryReader object called **`br2`** and are accessing the `.BaseStream.Position` property from **`br`**.

Answer (score 0):

Because br or  `br.BaseStream` is `null`.